# How can I get pandoc to generate double-spaced output in Word from markdown?

Tags: pandoc

How can I get pandoc to generate double-spaced Word docs from Markdown? My command line is this:

```
pandoc --smart -o foo.docx chap1.md chap2.md
```

I know I can insert a style sheet if I compile to HTML then run everything through wkhtmltopdf, but obviously wkhtmltopdf doesn't have .docx output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `reference.docx` file: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers

Get the default file:

```
pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > custom-reference.docx
```

Change the `Normal` style in `custom-reference.docx` to be double spaced. You can then compile your document with:

```
pandoc --smart -o foo.docx chap1.md chap2.md --reference-docx custom-reference.docx
```

Comment: Thank you! Beautiful summary! I somehow didn't understand the docs on this. Works a treat (with the minor problem that there is no explicit Normal style and I had to use the LibreOffice style named "Default Style"; still trying to find the LibreOffice equivalent to the code paragraph style).